# how to use sudo with curl command for setuptools install

Tags: python, django, curl, setuptools, askbot

I am trying to install python package, but when I try it tells me I need a new version of setup tools. I try to install setup tools following the python software instructions which say to use the curl command. When I do this it gives the error that I don't have permission to install in the directory. How can I use the curl command as a sudo user? I have tried several different ways. I have tried `sudo easy_install` and then the url, and also `sudo curl` url..

Comment: first do you have curl install in your system

Comment: yes i do, i type in man curl and all sorts of things come up

Comment: @ratrace123 did you try this? http://superuser.com/questions/550414/why-does-sudo-not-work-with-curl

Comment: Yes the link is good... did you try that, the same right way with my answer

Comment: yea i tried adding sudo after the pipe:                                                                                                           "curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo"                                     and now I get an error saying failed writing body. I think that it solved my original problem about how to run sudo with curl, now I just need to figure this out.

Comment: why not use wget to get  "wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right way to use curl and sudo. use sudo after the pipe

```
curl | sudo
```

e.g

```
curl https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

this might help

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | sudo python
```